# How do I find the original source of href="javascript:void(0)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying for hours to understand some public pages with public information, where they load

```
<a onclick="openStore();" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Store">Store</a>
```

How do I find the real `href` that it loads? Since this is javascript I guess this must be in the client side. Is that correct?

I guess I should be looking for a javascript function called "openStore()"?

Comment: *"I guess I should be looking for a javascript function called "openStore()"? Where might it be?"* In a JavaScript file?

Comment: $cookie-monster, sorry! I am not very experient with this! This javascript file is loaded by the same page?

Comment: Open console, go to source open all files search for that if it's not there it's in the html file

Comment: Start by learning JavaScript. As you do, you'll find out how to work with JavaScript in browser environments, and will be able to find the information you're looking for.

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the all of the javascript files for that function "openStore()".  You might have to keep digging into that function to determine the full URL being returned.  Using the browsers debug functions will help (f12 in IE or firefox w/ firebug)

Comment: Firefox w/o firebug includes developer tools that are more than sufficient for this task. It has the same hotkey (F12).

Comment: @Michael-Ford thank you! I found the function I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the Javascript code (either in the page itself or in an external loaded file) and look for the openStore() function.

Answer (score 2):

Using "javascript:" inside of the href attribute executes the following javascript code.

**void** happens to be an operator built into Javascript that evaluates the following expression and returns undefined.
[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

So what your code is doing is executing both the **void(0)** from the href, and the **openStore()** from the onclick. Inserting **javascript:void(0)** into the href attribute is a common way to make clicking a link do "nothing" while still telling the browser to stylize (treat) the anchor as a link.

In summary, you should be looking for the **openStore()** function.